# How to load .po/.mo files for localization in php site

Tags: php, localization, poedit, machine-translation

I create a messages.po and messages.mo files using poedit that contain strings which i want to show in spanish language.

To show my translations, i am using

```
<?php echo _("My text"); ?>
```

But i am facing the problem to load these files for translating my site text.

Here is the code which i am using to load the translations:

```
 $locale = "en_US";
 if (isset($_GET["lang"])) $locale = $_GET["lang"];
 putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
 setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
 bindtextdomain("messages", "./languages");
 textdomain("messages");
```

The languages folder is placed in the root and the the directory structure is

```
 languages/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
```

I am using http://mydomain?lang=es_ES in the url to run the site in spanish language.

Please tell me where i am wrong.